# What does this function do? And what is the odd syntax?

Tags: javascript

Can someone explain what this piece of code does. what is the test function testing for?

```
temp = "blah"
if ( /from_url=$/.test(temp) ) {
    //do something
}

test : function(s, p) {
    s = s.nodeType == 1 ? s.value : s;

    return s == '' || new RegExp(p).test(s);
}
```

Also in the initial condition what does the syntax if(/from_url=$/)  do?

Comment: this is not jQuery - its plain JavaScript - updated tags

Comment: I think he copied it from the jQuery source. At least the perverted amount of whitespace and the fact that the second block is apparently copied from an object literal really look like the jQuery source.

Comment: @ThiefMaster ahh ok - i will put the jQuery tag back ... ta

Comment: It was mainly to mention why he might have use it - I agree that the tag does not fit here as the code itself is not jQuery-specific.

Comment: @ThiefMaster i will quit editing this question :-) !!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`s = s.nodeType == 1 ? s.value : s;` if s.nodeType is 1 then use s.value, otherwise use s.

`return s == '' || new RegExp(p).test(s);` return s if it's an empty string, otherwise test if s is in the regular expression p.

`if(/from_url=$/)` is a regular expression that is looking for `from_url=` but only if it is at the very end.

Answer (score 1):

```
/from_url=$/
```

is a regular expression
which should translate to check the temp and find if it has 'from_url=' this text at the end of the string

Answer (score 0):

```
/from_url=$/
```

is a regular expression literal in JavaScript. You can replace it with

```
new RegExp('from_url=$')
```

This specific regular expression checks if the string ends with "`from_url=`" string.